# Media queries: How to make images responsive in Chrome for Windows Surface

Tags: css, google-chrome, media, surface

I have a responsive problem in my website but only with chrome for windows surface. The image is stretched across the browser, but the problem is fixed when resizing the browser window. Does anyone know how to fix this problem, or what could be the cause? Thanks in advance.

this is my css code:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .banner.lifest{
        height: 500px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px){
    .banner.lifest{
    height: 740px;
    }
}
```

This code works well for the rest of the browsers. It only stretches the images in chrome for windows surface.

Comment: If you set fix `height` and `width` for any image then it will gonna end up stretching one day or another.